# flask-SQLAlchemy OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

myapp.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
from view import *
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

view.py

```
from flask import render_template
from myapp import app
from model import db,User
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    aaa=User(username='admin',password='admin',email='xxx')
    db.session.add(aaa)
    db.session.commit()
    return 'commit user'
```

config.py

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL="mysql://%s:%s@%s/%s" % ('root', 'root', '127.0.0.1:3306', 'blog')
```

model.py

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from myapp import app
db=SQLAlchemy(app)
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__='user'
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True,unique=True)
    username=db.Column(db.String(45))
    password=db.Column(db.String(45))
    email=db.Column(db.String(45))
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

run myapp.py and visit `/test`:

> OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table user

I have already create database and table

Comment: It is very strange: you connect to the `MySQL` (in `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL`), but get an error from the `sqlite`. Try to check the settings again.

Comment: thank you very much,I spell SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI of SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL. sqlite maybe cache or something.

Comment: SQLite is the [default](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/fe67c633f2e6d66a01a1670e5fc6649506358d20/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L782) used by Flask-SQLAlchemy. Correcting that config variable name should fix the issue.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62148584/7483494

Comment: This is a typo: the correct config variable is `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` (cf [this issue](https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/1016))